# Adding rest of URL before shortened links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a Chrome extension for a browser game and one of the features I'd like to add is a floating "latest posts from the forum" window to the right of the game. I've gotten it displaying the way I want it to but, all of the links pulled from the forum are shortened and don't include the full URL. When I click on one of the links it tries to go to that page on the games site rather than the forum site. What I'd like is for my code to fix the URL as well as add a target blank attribute so the links open in a new page/tab. My existing code is below.

```
$(function(){
    var hzsforumpostsss = document.getElementById('latestpostsHZ');
    hzsforumpostsss.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div><div id=\"hzlatestforumss\" style=\"background-color: rgba(0, 110, 187, 0.9);position:absolute;left:50%;width:280px;margin-left:390px;font-size:9pt;display:block;overflow:auto;\"></div></div>');
    $('#hzlatestforumss').load('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://heroes-rising-forum.2349640.n4.nabble.com/');
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're just loading the content directly into your div with some AJAX, you're going to need to loop through all the links in the div and prepend the hostname to the ones which are relative. Your mix of jQuery and vanilla JS is a little confusing, but I'll just stick to vanilla JS for my example code.

```
[...document.getElementById('hzlatestforumss').getElementsByTagName('a')].forEach(anchor => {
  if (anchor.href && !anchor.href.includes('://')) {
    if (!anchor.href.startsWith('/')) { anchor.href = '/' + anchor.href; }
    anchor.href = 'http://heroes-rising-forum.2349640.n4.nabble.com' + anchor.href;
  }
});
```

You can also add the _blank target in the same loop if you want.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but, how do I add this to my existing script? I tried just appending it to the end before my closing }) and it doesn't seem to do anything. The div still draws but, the links are still all the short type.

Comment: The `load()` function in jQuery that you're using is asynchronous. That means the code will continue even before it's loaded the data from the URL you gave it. You need to wait for the data to be loaded before you try to change the HREFs (as they don't exist before then). Check the jQuery docs for `load()` -- I believe the third argument is a completion callback to run after the data is fully loaded, which is where you would put this code.

Comment: Thanks for getting me on the right track! The code I ended up using is below.

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU for getting me on the right track! The code I ended up with is below.

```
$(function(){
    var hzsforumpostsss = document.getElementById('latestpostsHZ');
    hzsforumpostsss.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div><div id=\"hzlatestforumss\"'+
    'style=\"background-color: rgba(0, 110, 187, 0.9);position:absolute;left:50%;width:280px;margin-left:390px;display:block;overflow:auto;\"></div></div>');
    $('#hzlatestforumss').load('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://heroes-rising-forum.2349640.n4.nabble.com/');
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('a[href*="/"]').each(function(){
    var current = $(this).attr("href");
    $(this).attr("href", "http://heroes-rising-forum.2349640.n4.nabble.com" + current);
    $(this).attr("target", "_blank");
    });
    },2000);
})
```

Comment: Using setTimeout is not a good solution. What if the user is on a slow internet connection and it takes more than 2 seconds to fetch the data for loading? You really should be putting the processing code *in the completion callback* of the `load()` method, to guarantee it'll always run after the data has been loaded.

Comment: I totally get the slow connection comment. I started with a smaller timeout and had to increase it to what I hoped was a happy medium for most folks. Your suggestion sounds much better! How would I go about doing as you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$(function(){
    var hzsforumpostsss = document.getElementById('latestpostsHZ');
    hzsforumpostsss.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div class="HideFJcontainer" style=\"position:absolute;left:50%;width:280px;margin-left:390px;display:block;overflow:auto;\">'+
    '<input type="checkbox" class="HideFJforum">&nbsp;Hide/Show Forum<div id=\"hzlatestforumss\"></div></div>');
    $('#hzlatestforumss').load('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://heroes-rising-forum.2349640.n4.nabble.com/',
    function(){
    $('a[href*="/"]').each(function(){
    var current = $(this).attr("href");
    $(this).attr("href", "http://heroes-rising-forum.2349640.n4.nabble.com" + current);
    $(this).attr("target", "_blank");
    });
    } );
```

Comment: Did you try that? Because I think it should work, if you fix what looks like a missing closing bracket at the end. (It's hard to tell; please use proper indentation to make your code easier to read.) Although keep in mind your selector there is `a[href*="/"]` which means it'll target EVERY such link on your page, not just the ones inside the `hzlatestforumss` box.

Comment: Oh - thanks for pointing that out! 

I changed the code to be ```$('.adbayes-content a[href*="/"]')``` which makes it unique to the loaded content.

Comment: I don't see where the `adbayes-content` class exists in the code you've showed, but if it works, great! (I was thinking something more like `#hzlatestforumss a[href*="/"]` would work.)